# What is this item with many small gadgets on a keyhole-shaped ring?

Tags: tools

I found this in a tool box when I was cleaning out my dad's garage. Does anyone know what it is and it's used for? It says kirsch in the inside. I don't know if there all exactly the same size but I couldn't find another pic of it online.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kirsch makes drapery hardware.  That looks like a shower curtain ring with a bunch of drapery rod slides collected on it.

Comment: You can get some more here! :-D  https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/203504779835?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20200818143230%26meid%3Dd29920c4c62644838b88cb0f45a8604a%26pid%3D101224%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D5%26sd%3D185607708699%26itm%3D203504779835%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DDefaultOrganicWeb&_trksid=p2047675.c101224.m-1 -  Well, they're very similar.

Comment: Knew the slides looked familiar, couldn't remember where I'd seen them.. If something in a toolbox doesn't make sense as a tool, it's probably spare parts.

Comment: I thought they were button-sized 1-Wire RFID keys at first, those used to be popular on gates of recreation parcs around here, but couldn't imagine how you'd collect so many of them.

Comment: Definitely shower-curtain attachments. :)

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - I don't quite see the similarity. From your images: ["Front" side](https://images2.imgbox.com/ba/52/gAqS574w_o.jpg), ["Back" side](https://images2.imgbox.com/d2/4c/etH2OETK_o.jpg) yours is of a spring loaded clip, OP's image has no spring. Also, OP's image has a "button" attachment piece allowing it to slide along a track, yours does not.